# How to send mails by selecting each dropdown value with differenet fields?

Tags: magento-1.8

I had created the dropdwon list with lab,pharmacy,food,Gym and Nurse and When I select lab it shows some fields(ex:name,city,location,etc) and when I select pharmacy it shows some fields as(ex:medicine name,name,email) in the same it generates for other dropdown lists also.

I need to send the mails with these information with different body for customer,admin and for provider emails.

But I can send for only for lab and not for others.Please help me.

Comment: did you done with attachment?

Comment: No.they said to stop on that because without that I need to send the email

Comment: last code i send it was working perfectly  and tested too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <?php
//Admin Mail
function sendMailAction(){
 //Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);



$html="";
if($_POST['servicetype']=='Lab')
    {
      $testname=$_POST['testname'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['labemail'];
$mobile=$_POST['labmobile'];

     $city=$_POST['rcity'];
    $zip_code=$_POST['labzip_code'];
     $html .='<p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
     <p>Test Name: '.$testname.'</p>
     <p>Email : '.$email.'</p>
     <p>Mobile Number: '.$mobile.'</p>
     <p>City: '.$city.'</p>
     <p>Zip Code: '.$zip_code.'</p>';
    }else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Pharmacy')
     {
     $medicine=$_POST['medicinename'];

    $testname=$_POST['testname'];
$name=$_POST['pname'];
$email=$_POST['pemail'];
$mobile=$_POST['pmobile'];

     $city=$_POST['pcity'];
    $zip_code=$_POST['pzip_code'];
     $html .='<p> Medicine: '.$medicine.'</p><p> Email: '.$email.'</p>
     <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>


     <p>Mobile Number: '.$labmobile.'</p>
     <p>City: '.$rcity.'</p>
     <p>Zip Code: '.$labzip_code.'</p>';
     }else {



$name=$_POST['fname'];
$email=$_POST['femail'];
$mobile=$_POST['fmobile'];

     $city=$_POST['fcity'];
    $zip_code=$_POST['fzip_code'];
     $html .='<p> Email: '.$email.'</p>
     <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>

     <p>Email : '.$email.'</p>
     <p>Mobile Number: '.$labmobile.'</p>
     <p>City: '.$rcity.'</p>
     <p>Zip Code: '.$labzip_code.'</p>';
     }


  $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
  $mail->setToName('admin');
  $mail->setToEmail($email);
  $mail->setBody($html);
  $mail->setSubject('Blood Donor');
  $mail->setFromEmail('admin@labwise.in');
  $mail->setFromName("Labwise");
//$mail->addBcc("admin@labwise.in");
 $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format

 try {
 //$mail->send();

}
 catch (Exception $e) {

}
}
//Customer Mail

function sendMailcustomerAction(){

 $email=$_POST['email'];
 $servicetype=$_POST['servicetype'];
     $testname=$_POST['testname'];
   $name=$_POST['name'];
   $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
   $city=$POST_['city'];

$html=
'Dear '.$name.',

    <p>We have received your order for '.$testname.'. You will be attended shortly.</p>

    <p>Best Regards,</p>
    <p>Team Labwise.</p>'

 ;
  $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
  $mail->setToName($name);
  $mail->setToEmail($email);
  $mail->setBody($html);
  $mail->setSubject('Blood Donor');
  $mail->setFromEmail('admin@labwise.in');
  $mail->setFromName("Labwise");
 //$mail->addBcc("contact@labwise.in");
  $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format

   try {
   $mail->send();

  return '<h2>Your Order has been submitted. Thank you for using labwise.   </h2>';

  }
  catch (Exception $e) {

 return '</h2>Unable to submit.</h2>';

 }
 }

 //service provider details for whose isblooddonor is true

   $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');  
    if($_POST['servicetype']=='Lab')
{
        $allrecord =$readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.islab=?', '1'
          );
  } else  if($_POST['servicetype']=='Pharmacy')
{
        $allrecord =$readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.pharmacy=?', '1'
          );
  }else  if($_POST['servicetype']=='Gym')
{
        $allrecord =$readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.gym=?', '1'
          );
  }else  if($_POST['servicetype']=='Food')
{
        $allrecord =$readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.food=?', '1'
          );
  }else  if($_POST['servicetype']=='Nurse')
{
        $allrecord =$readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.nurse=?', '1'
          );
  }else  if($_POST['servicetype']=='Physio')
{
        $allrecord =$readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.physio=?', '1'
          );
  }
         $alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);
         foreach($alldata as $data)
         {
              sendMailserviceAction($data['email'],$data['name']);
         }

         function sendMailserviceAction($ssemail,$pname){
     //Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);
     $html="";
if($_POST['servicetype']=='Lab')
    {
      $testname=$_POST['testname'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['labemail'];
$mobile=$_POST['labmobile'];

     $city=$_POST['rcity'];
    $zip_code=$_POST['labzip_code'];
     $html .='<p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
     <p>Test Name: '.$testname.'</p>
     <p>Email : '.$email.'</p>
     <p>Mobile Number: '.$mobile.'</p>
     <p>City: '.$city.'</p>
     <p>Zip Code: '.$zip_code.'</p>';
    }else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Pharmacy')
     {
     $medicine=$_POST['medicinename'];

    $testname=$_POST['testname'];
$name=$_POST['pname'];
$email=$_POST['pemail'];
$mobile=$_POST['pmobile'];

     $city=$_POST['pcity'];
    $zip_code=$_POST['pzip_code'];
     $html .='<p> Medicine: '.$medicine.'</p><p> Email: '.$email.'</p>
     <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>


     <p>Mobile Number: '.$labmobile.'</p>
     <p>City: '.$rcity.'</p>
     <p>Zip Code: '.$labzip_code.'</p>';
     }else {



$name=$_POST['fname'];
$email=$_POST['femail'];
$mobile=$_POST['fmobile'];

     $city=$_POST['fcity'];
    $zip_code=$_POST['fzip_code'];
     $html .='<p> Email: '.$email.'</p>
     <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>

     <p>Email : '.$email.'</p>
     <p>Mobile Number: '.$labmobile.'</p>
     <p>City: '.$rcity.'</p>
     <p>Zip Code: '.$labzip_code.'</p>';
     }

     $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
      $mail->setToName($pname);
     $mail->setToEmail($ssemail);
     $mail->setBody($html);
     $mail->setSubject('Quick Service');
     $mail->setFromEmail('admin@labwise.in');
     $mail->setFromName("Labwise");
    //$mail->addBcc("admin@labwise.in");
     echo $htm;
    $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format

       try {
      $mail->send();
      //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your Order is successfully Completed');
      //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
    //return '<h2>Your Order has been submitted. Thank you for using labwise.   </h2>';
      //$this->_redirect('');
      }
     catch (Exception $e) {
      //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
       //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
      //return '</h2>Unable to submit.</h2>'; 
     //$this->_redirect('');
     }
     }

    echo sendMailserviceAction();
   echo sendMailcustomerAction();
   echo sendMailAction();

?>
```

add this code for uploading the file and make sure folder have right of 777

```
 if( !empty($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])  and $_POST['servicetype']=='Pharmacy')
        { 

            $image_ext = end(explode('.',$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]));
            $allowed_ext =  array('gif','png' ,'jpg','jpeg','pdf','doc','docx','rtf','odt');

            $uploadfilename = md5(substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, rand(1,100).rand(1,100))).str_replace(" ","_",$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]); 
             $source_upl         = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
            $target_path_upl = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename;  
            if(in_array($image_ext ,$allowed_ext ) ) {
                @move_uploaded_file($source_upl, $target_path_upl);
            }
        }
```

and this attachment code add it before sending email.

```
if(file_exists(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename) )
    {

      $attachment = file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename);
      $ext = pathinfo($uploadfilename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
      $file = new Zend_Mime_Part($attachment);
      $file->filename    = $uploadfilename;
      $file->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT;
      $file->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
      $mail->addAttachment($file);
    }
```

Comment: For each service type I need to send three mails 1.for customer and 2.for admin 3.for service provider as islab=1 for lab and ispharmacy=1 for pharmacy and isgym=1 for Gym

Comment: added check in collection and for admin and customer you already set emails.

Comment: It is only for service type= lab and when islab is checkedand when I select pharmacy,food,gym in the same way it has to send the emails for admin,customer also they have different fields for each service type

Comment: i added the check in query and also in email. also add foe field in email copy any where you want to send it's work

Comment: below you have posted upto pharmacy and not for food.Can u please the full code with admin mail and customer mail.I am getting confusing

Comment: `echo sendMailserviceAction();
      echo sendMailcustomerAction();
      echo sendMailAction(); ` is these which are sending email to admin and which is sending mail to customer?

Comment: sendMailserviceAction()-provider,sendMailcustomerAction()-customer sendMailAction()-admin

Comment: add this code in every email   `if($_POST['servicetype']=='lab')
    {
     $city=$_POST['city'];
    $country=$_POST['country'];
     $html .='<p> City: '.$city.'</p><p> Country: '.$country.'</p>';
    }else if($_POST['servicetype']=='pharmacy')
     {
     $medicine=$_POST['medicine'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
     $html .='<p> Medicine: '.$medicine.'</p><p> Email: '.$email.'</p>';
     }` after the `$html`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32296/discussion-between-mouni-and-qaisar-satti).

Comment: Ok After $html there is some message in every mai.What it does

Comment: it will add extra field you added for lab and also pharmacy and kindly add the remaining field too in these

Comment: No.I am not getting any mail

Comment: echo $_POST['servicetype']; check this value.

Comment: @QaisarSatti.Please give me reply and update the code.

Comment: wait i am checking that

Comment: you are repeating the same filed name again and again that you are not getting the output.

Comment: I have modified my code and sent you the mail.Please review it

Comment: added the answer with working functionality

Comment: I could not print the servicetype.I am not getting the value

Comment: In Pharmacy you have used labmobile details and labzipcode details

Comment: i tested this code and it is fully working without any problem

Comment: adjust these on your requirement

Comment: Can you please check for attachment and suggest me

Comment: Sent the latest code.Please check it and update the code

Comment: @Qaissar satti Please update the attachment code

Comment: @Mouni last two day i was busy too much i tried do that today..

Comment: @@Qaissar satti please update the attachment code.I need to submit it by th evening.Please help me .I had tried in different ways but it is not working.

Comment: updated the code kindly check..

Comment: No.I am not getting any mail.But the attached file is saving in requestquote folder

Comment: Remove the attachment code and then check working or not

Comment: By removing the attachment code it is working fine

Comment: Let me check with that..

Comment: Is it working for you.Please reply me

Comment: i am working not have live server now not able to check email.